# Poisson process on nonintersecting sets

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I try to show that for a homogeneous Poisson process $N$ with intensity $\lambda$ and nonintersecting sets $A,B$ the amount of events happening in the two sets are independent. My idea is to prove the following 
$$P(N(A) = n, N(B) =z)=P(N(A\cup B)= n+z)=P(N(A) = n)P(N(B) =z)$$
the first equality comes from $A\cap B=\emptyset$ but I fail to show the next one because of the factorial
$$P(N(A\cup B)= n+z)=\frac{(\lambda|A\cup B|)^{n+z}}{(n+z)!}e^{-\lambda(|A\cup B|)}$$

I would appreciate some help, thanks

Edit:

My definition of a HPP 
$N$:

1. For some $\lambda > 0$ and finite planar region $A$, we have a Poisson distribution, i.e. $$N(A)\sim \text{Poi}(\lambda \cdot  |A|)$$
2. Given $N(A)=n$, the $n$ events in $A$ are an independent sample from the uniform distribution on $A$

Comment: What is your precise definition of Poisson process?

Comment: @kimchilover Hi, I added the definition into the question

Comment: The first equality isn't quite correct. Suppose $n\neq 0$. Then,

$$\{N(A) = 0,N(B) = n+z\} \subseteq \{N(A\cup B) = n+k\}\setminus \{N(A) = n,N(B) = z\},$$

This shows that $P(N(A) = n,N(B) = z) \leq P(N(A\cup B) = n+z),$ and the inequality is strict when $n+z \neq 0$.

As a hint, try using the second property. Notice that conditioned on the event $\{N(A\cup B) = n+z\}$, $N(A)$ is binomially distributed with success probability $\frac{|A|}{|A|+|B|}$.

Comment: @forgottenarrow I tried working with the conditional probability and I get this. Let $p:=|A|/(|A|+|B|)$ then $$P(N(A)=n, N(A\cup B)=n+z)=\frac{(\lambda \cdot |A \cup B|)^{n+z}}{(n+z)!}e^{-\lambda \cdot |A \cup B|}(\frac{n+z}{n})p^n(1-p)^z$$ I don't understand the second property fully, can you write it mathematically for me? It is something like $P(\cdot| N(A)=n)\sim Uni(A)$ but what is the $\cdot$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity of notation let $X=N(A)$, $Y=N(B)$ and $Z=X+Y=N(A\cup B)=N(A)+N(B)$, let $a = EX = \lambda|A|$ and $b=EY$.

The probability that $(X,Y)=(k,l)$ can be found by conditioning on $Z$ as follows:
$$\begin{align*}
P((X,Y)=(k,l)) &= \sum_{n\ge0}P(Z=n)\times P((X,Y)=(k,l)|Z=n)\\
&=P(Z=k+l)\times  P((X,Y)=(k,l)|Z=k+l)\tag{*}\\
&=\frac{(a+b)^{k+l}}{(k+l)!}e^{-(a+b)}\times P((X,Y)=(k,l)|Z=k+l)\\
&= \frac{(a+b)^{k+l}}{(k+l)!}e^{-(a+b)}\times  \binom{k+l}k 
\left(\frac a{a+b}\right)^k \left(\frac b{a+b}\right)^l\\
&= \frac{(a+b)^{k+l}}{(k+l)!}e^{-(a+b)}\times \frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!} 
\left(\frac a{a+b}\right)^k \left(\frac b{a+b}\right)^l\\
&= \frac{a^k}{k!}e^{-a}\,\frac {b^l}{l!} e^{-b}\\
&= P(X=k)P(Y=l).
\end{align*}$$
Here (*) holds because all terms $P((X,Y)=(k,l)|Z=n)$ vanish, except when $n=k+l$.

In words: the variables $X,Y,Z$ are definitely *not* independent. 
 But when $Z$ is Poisson and $X$ conditional on $Z$ is binomial and conditional on $Z$ we have $Y=Z-X$, magically the right factorials cancel to make $X$ and $Y$ independent.

Comment: Thank you a lot!